# Help interpret will_paginate docs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

Trying to understand the options for will_paginate's [`paginate`](http://gitrdoc.com/mislav/will_paginate/tree/master/) method:

```
:page — REQUIRED, but defaults to 1 if false or nil
:per_page — defaults to CurrentModel.per_page (which is 30 if not overridden)
:total_entries — use only if you manually count total entries
:count — additional options that are passed on to count
:finder — name of the ActiveRecord finder used (default: “find”)
```

`page`, `per_page`, and `finder` are straightforward.

`total_entries` and `count` -- don't understand "use only if you manually count entries?" Are they envisioning a scenario where you'd run a separate count query, then pass the result to `paginate` as an option? What would be the circumstances where you'd do that?

"additional options that are passed on to count" -- What options are available? "Pass on" to the `count` method of ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default will_paginate uses count (from [ActiveRecord::Calculations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html)) to figure out the total number of objects you're paging through. But if you know better, or straight count won't work, you can calculate and provide :total_entries yourself.

The :count parameter is for extra arguments to the ActiveRecord::Calculations#count method, like :distinct. You can look at the docs for the complete list.

Comment: providing :total_entries does not seem to be working anymore. COUNT(*) queries are still hitting the database

Answer (score 0):

The total_entries and count parameters can be used when you want to paginate different models in the same list, or if you want to perform a complex query. As long as you don't need it, don't worry about it. When you run into problems you can't seem to solve, check back.